# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while using LZMA-js

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression, lzma

I am trying to compress a string using the LZMA-JS library found [here](https://github.com/LZMA-JS/LZMA-JS). Here is my javascript:

```
var reader  = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var big_code = reader.result;
    console.log(big_code.length);
    var my_lzma = new LZMA();
    my_lzma.compress(my_lzma, 1, on_finish(result, error) {
        code = result;
    });
    console.log(code.length);
}, false);
```

The error occurs on this line

```
my_lzma.compress(my_lzma, 1, on_finish(result, error) { //the rest occurs below
```

However, when I change this line by removing the `{}` brackets like this

```
my_lzma.compress(my_lzma, 1, on_finish(result, error));
```

the error goes away. Unfortunately this makes the code useless because I need the `result`.

I have looked around the internet for over an hour trying to find a solution to this error. I don't believe this is a duplicate because I have not found anything related.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is perhaps confusing - the function's role, not name, is `on_finish`, so use this instead to indicate you are creating an in-line function:

```
my_lzma.compress(my_lzma, 1, function (result, error) {
    code = result;
});
```

See the [example usage here](https://github.com/LZMA-JS/LZMA-JS/blob/master/demos/simple_node_demo.js#L10).